# Elasticsearch field name inference

Tags: c#, .net, nest

I have documents with dynamic names, for example:

```
{
    "field.customerA": 4,
    "field.customerB": 10
}
```

and my POCO object has only "field" in it:

```
public class Poco {
    public string field {get; set;}
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to populate field property with a specific value of field for customer from docs. the customer is known in runtime.
Is it possible to achieve such a result? maybe with some kind of deserialization?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching and reading, I finally implemented a `SourceSerializer`, as suggested in
[custom serialization](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/custom-serialization.html)